# vba simple range/object error

Tags: excel, vba, object, range

So I thought I had an OK grasp of VBA but now this error is really bugging me and I can't figure out the problem.
Here is an incredibly short subroutine (run from a module):

```
Sub test()
    Dim lr
    lr = Sheets(1).Range("a1", Cells(65, 1))
    MsgBox lr.Address
End Sub
```

For whatever reason this throws up an "application defined/object defined error"

can anyone explain?

Edit:
This also throws up the same error:

```
MsgBox Sheets(1).Range("a1", Cells(65, 1)).Address
```

Edit2:
I'm going to change my question a bit as I understand about the object thing but I what to use it with the "find" method.
So here is the code:

```
Set lookrange = Sheets(1).Range(Cells(2, 1), Cells(200, 1))
Set result = lookrange.Find(what:=searchTerm, lookat:=xlWhole)
```

In this case it tells me lookrange is causing a problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok. You've got several problems.

```
Option Explicit
sub test()
    Dim lr as Range
    set lr = Sheets(1).Range("a1", Cells(65, 1))
    MsgBox lr.Address
End Sub
```

First, as someone who is new to VBA, use `Option Explicit` nearly always at the tops of your modules so you are required to dimension your variables.

Second, you never declare `lr` as an object type - make sure you declare it as a type `Range` - you don't necessarily have to do this, however, it is good practice.

Third, you need to use `set` as others have indicated when assigning objects such as `Range` values or you will always get that error.

---

Onto the second part of your question.

```
MsgBox Sheets(1).Range("a1", Cells(65, 1)).Address
```

Change this to

```
With Sheets(1)
    MsgBox .Range(.Range("A1"), .Cells(65, 1)).Address
End With
```

If you are ever running this from a sheet different than `Sheet1` you will get errors, because the `Cells(65,1)` reference will not be on `Sheet1` - Excel will think you mean the current worksheet.

---

The third part

```
Set lookrange = Sheets(1).Range(Cells(2, 1), Cells(200, 1))
Set result = lookrange.Find(what:=searchTerm, lookat:=xlWhole)
```

Has the same issue as second part. Also note it is entirely possible you will run errors if `result` cannot be found and the second statement above (the results of `Find`) will cause errors if `Find` is unsuccessful.

Comment: Since the OP is relatively new with VBA(in theory), would you please suggest he use `With Sheets(1)` instead of using `Sheets(1)` 3 times in 1 line? It's much prettier and doesn't make me cringe.

Answer (score 0):

Probably your range definition is not correct...Not sure what you are trying to achieve there but sheets(1).range(myrange) returns a range object.

```
Sub tetPop()

    Call popAddress(10, 12)
    Call popAddress(14, 21)
    Call popAddress(11, 18)

End Sub

Sub popAddress(ByVal row As Integer, ByVal col As Integer)

    Dim lr As Range

    Set lr = Sheets(1).Range("a1", Cells(row, col))
    MsgBox lr.Address

    ' or better and direct
    MsgBox Sheets(1).Range("a1", Cells(row, col)).Address

End Sub
```

Would popup different address 
Cheers

Daniel

Comment: Sure but the code above is not my programme, it is just the but that is causing a problem. I need to use the cells(x,x) method as the bottom of the range is not fixed and I intend to replace the 65 with a variable. The address method is also not relevant, I just don't know why it doesn't work, either as an object or just a range

Comment: you can use this same notation using a variable for the 65 by using set lr = sheets(1).range("A1:A" & variablename)

Answer (score 0):

The point is that `lr = Sheets(1).Range("a1", Cells(65, 1))` returns a range object.
Emphasis on *object*. So you need to use `set` at the start, as Daniel did.
As you assign that object without `set`, Excel uses the default property, which is Range.Value. So the assignment does not throw an error, only using lr as an object does.

Comment: Your 'edit'-line should not throw an error, though, and it does not do so as I'm testing it.