# excel 2010 vba "find" function returns contents

Tags: excel, vba, function, find

When I execute this vba sub the values returned from find in the variables Temp1 and Search are the contents of the cell, not a range variable with the cell address.

The code is here:

```
Sub updateFDFList(Fname As String)    
   '  Check for worksheet existence

   'last filled row
   Dim lastLine As Long
   lastLine = Worksheets("FDFFiles").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).row

   If lastLine = 1 Then
     'List Is Empty
     Worksheets("FDFFiles").Cells(2, 1).Value = Fname
     Worksheets("FDFFiles").Cells(2, 2).Value = "No"
  Else
     'Search column A for match
     Dim Search As Range
     S1 = "A2:A" & lastLine
     With Range(S1)
        Temp1 = .Find(Fname)
        Search = .Find(Fname, LookAt:=xlWhole, MatchCase:=True)
        If Search Is Nothing Then
           Dim newLine
           newLine = lastLine + 1
           Worksheets("FDFFiles").Cells(newLine, 1).Value = Fname
           Worksheets("FDFFiles").Cells(newLine, 2).Value = "No"
        End If
      End With
   End If
End Sub
```

Comment: You need to Set range objects: `Set Search = .Find(Fname, LookAt:=xlWhole, MatchCase:=True)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After you declared the the `Range` object you need to instantiate it with the `Set` keyword.

Here is a good and simple description: http://www.excel-easy.com/vba/range-object.html

This says:

> **Declare a Range Object**
>   You can declare a Range object by using the keywords Dim and Set.

Without the `Set`, it returns the `Value` of the cell.

The answer to this question explains it in detail: [vba simple range/object error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12711519/vba-simple-range-object-error/12712673#12712673)

And here is the full description with examples from msdn: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff838238.aspx